# datagridview removes '&' character from strings

Tags: vb.net, string, datagridview

In VB.Net 2012 I have a datagridview with a text column, a button and a label on a form.
The button executes to following code:

```
 Label1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

If I type *"foobar"* into the first cell the label displays *"foobar"* like it should.
But if I type *"&foo&bar&"* into the cell and click the button the label displays ***"foobar"*** ???
`Cell.Value.ToString` appears to remove the `'&'` character from the text.
Why does this happen and can I work around it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You to see a ampersand character in windows form control, you must use two ampersand characters because windows forms controls use the ampersand character to determine the shortcut key (Alt + key), where key is the key following the ampersand.

One way to solve is the following:

```
Label1.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Replace("&", "&&")
```